# entire page image gallery load/resize technique

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, wordpress, gallery

i'm curious about an effect i've seen on a lot of different wordpress powered sites. i think it might be a plugin, but i'm not entirely sure.

it's basically a page of images of different sizes, and they fit together based on how wide your window is. they also rearrange very stylishly when you resize your window.

the images also load as you scroll down, in sort of an infitie scroll way.

here is a perfect example of what i'm talking about... http://www.someoddpilot.com/work/projects/

how are they doing that? i would like to achieve a similiar effect, but i'm not sure where to begin. any insight would be super helpful, i'm somewhat new at this. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several techniques... I didn't look to see what they are using specifically, but since you mention jQuery, there is a plugin you should check out:  **[Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)**

[image]

Comment: oh wow, this is cool thanks. is there a separate method to only load images that are in the window? and load the rest as you scroll to them?

Comment: @patricko, You would have to code it separately, but yes, that would be possible.

Comment: oh no, isotope even has an infinite scroll option. this is perfect thank you. i had no idea this existed.

Comment: You mention several techniques. If you elaborate, you will earn my upvote.

Comment: You could try Masonry plugin, Isotope plugin (small license fee), Wookmarks plugin, jQuery Tiles plugin, Metro JS plugin...